# CakePHP Paginator Link with Image?

Tags: image, cakephp, hyperlink, pagination

**I want to combine Paginator-Link with an image.**

To load an image I use: (Displays the image, without any problem)

```
$this->Html->image('arrow_up.png');
```

My custom Paginator Link:  (Displays the link, without any problem)

```
$this->Paginator->link('',array('sort' => 'Item.vidduration', 'direction' => 'desc'));
```

.

.

Both together will **show a link and no image:**

```
$this->Paginator->link($this->Html->image('arrow_up.png', array("alt" => "Duration DESC")),array('sort' => 'Item.vidduration', 'direction' => 'desc'));
```

output:

```
<img src="/img/arrow_up.png" alt="Duration DESC" />
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The output is an img tag, but you say that it shows a link and no image? Should that be the other way around or am I missing something?

Comment: You should probably use CSS instead

Comment: yes, it should be the other way around.
I can't use CSS as I'm calling the Paginator through php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->link($html->image('arrow_up.png', array("alt" => "Duration DESC")),array('sort' => 'Item.vidduration', 'direction' => 'desc'), $options = array('escape' => false)); ?>
```